# Linux won't boot after install for Dell PowerEdge 2850 in SCSI Mode

Tags: centos, boot, dell-poweredge

I was successfully able to install CentOS 6.5 x86_64 Minimal from CD, and setup software raid during the install steps, after having set the Dell PowerEdge 2850 to SCSI Mode which enabled CentOS to see all the drives. Everything appeared to go smoothly, like previous installs I've done on other servers (perhaps not this same make/model) and desktops.

But, after rebooting the server acted like it didn't know there was anything to boot. I checked BIOS boot priorities and the LSI boot tool and made sure things looked like they were setup to boot. During the post boot up I see the drives listed as expected.

It appears to just hang, as well, no message about failing to find a bootable device. It just hangs after the IPMI step I believe.

Any ideas why the server is acting like it can't see the OS to boot?

Thanks

Comment: Drivers or firmware?  I seem to remember having the same problem with a Dell server of that vintage, which I solved by upgrading the controller firmware from the 1.00 version which wasn't supported in CentOS to... Well, the most recent one (at the time), which worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll see if there's anything to that.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a GPT partition table? If so, you need a bios_grub aka "Reserved BIOS boot area" partition (not the same as /boot) or things don't work right, especially with software raid. Also with grub and Linux softraid, your /boot should be raid1, and ideally not metadata 1.2.